# C++ variable alias - what's that exactly, and why is it better to turn if off?

Tags: c++, variable-alias

I've read the essay [Surviving the Release Version](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/survivereleasever.aspx).

Under the "Aliasing bugs" clause it says:

> You can get tighter code if you tell
>   the compiler that it can assume no
>   aliasing....

I've also read [Aliasing (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29).

What exactly is a variable alias? I understand it means using a pointer to a variable is an alias, but, how/why does it affect badly, or in other words - why telling the compiler that it can assume no aliasing would get me a "tighter code"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disallowing aliasing means if you have a pointer `char* b`, you can assume that b is the only pointer in the program that points to that particular memory location, which means the only time that memory location is going to change is when the programmer uses `b` to change it. The generated assembly thus doesn't need to reload the memory pointed to by `b` into a register as long as the compiler knows nothing has used `b` to modify it. If aliasing is allowed it's possible there's another pointer `char* c = b;` that was used elsewhere to mess with that memory

Comment: "The generated assembly thus doesn't need to reload the memory pointed to by b..." . That's all I needed, thank you. Actually, after reading your answer, only then I really understood Samuel's answer, as yours like completed the puzzle. Thank you both then!!

Answer (score 13):

Aliasing is when you have two different references to the same underlying memory.  Consider this made up example:

```
int doit(int *n1, int *n2)
{
    int x = 0;

    if (*n1 == 1)
    {
        *n2 = 0;

        x += *n1  // line of interest
    }

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    doit(&x, &x);   // aliasing happening
}
```

If the compiler has to allow for aliasing, it needs to consider the possibility that `n1 == n2`.  Therefore, when it needs to use the value of `*n1` at "line of interest", it needs to allow for the possibility it was changed by the line `*n2 = 0`.

If the compiler can assume no aliasing, it can assume at "line of interest" that `*n1 == 1` (because otherwise we would not be inside the `if`).  The optimizer can then use this information to optimize the code (in this case, change "line of interest" from following the pointer and doing a general purpose addition to using a simple increment).